# Ping fails: is a webserver configuration issue or not?

Tags: ubuntu, web-server, ping

When I ping a dedicated ip on my server I get the following:

```
ping XXX.XXX.95.175
PING XXX.XXX.95.175 (109.72.95.175): 56 data bytes
Request timeout for icmp_seq 0
Request timeout for icmp_seq 1
Request timeout for icmp_seq 2
Request timeout for icmp_seq 3
```

If I ping the main ip on my server instead it works:

```
ping XXX.XXX.95.174
PING XXX.XXX.95.174 (109.72.95.174): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from XXX.XXX.95.174: icmp_seq=0 ttl=57 time=15.813 ms
64 bytes from XXX.XXX.95.174: icmp_seq=1 ttl=57 time=15.183 ms
64 bytes from XXX.XXX.95.174: icmp_seq=2 ttl=57 time=36.285 ms
```

So I was now wondering: is it an issue in my webserver configuration file or should I contact my hosting provider ?

They already told me that it is my webserver configuration issue.. but I'm not sure about it.. could you give me some tip please ?

**Update**

Should I just add this ?

```
iface eth0:1 inet static
address XXX.XXX.95.175
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway XXX.XXX.95.174
```

Comment: if your paying for support, use it!

Comment: I think your update is almost correct for Debian (and possibly other distributions) except that I think you should use eth0:0 and the gateway should be the same as the gateway value for the main eth0.

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick Ok cool (I'm on Ubuntu). I was actually wondering if this configuration could create issues to SSL certificate. I mean.. am I redirecting the traffic to my old ip ? Or am I effectively using the first ip ? I don't want to find out later that the SSL certificate doesn't work because of this.

Comment: No you are not really redirecting traffic to a different destination address, your single network interface will now accept packets with either destination address. I'm not sure how this affects your SSL certificates - aren't they tied to hostnames?.

Comment: I've retagged your question with a 'Ubuntu' tag (it would have been helpful to know this earlier)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a potential problem of terminology. When people say "webserver" they might be referring to either

- The application that listens for HTTP requests. e.g. Apache HTTPD server.
- A computer whose primary purpose is to run such an application.

### In the first sense

Ping failure is nothing to do with webserver configuration.

Ping normally uses the ICMP protocol.

Webservers use HTTP over TCP over IP protocols.

### Generally

If you cannot ping an IP-address then you have a networking problem that might lie at the client end (the PC where you type the ping command), in the LAN (e.g. port failure on a switch) or in the server (misconfiguration or NIC failure).

On the computer that runs your webserver, check the configuration

- Windows: ipconfig /all
- Unix/Linux: ifconfig -a

Check that one of the interfaces has the address XXX.XXX.95.175 and is "Up".

Check that any firewall on the server is not blocking ping (e.g. blocking ICMP)

---

### EDIT:

If the server has a single network interface (NIC), you can run two IP-addresses on a single card by using an IP alias. On Linux servers this can usually be accomplished using the `ifconfig` command and using a `:0` suffix for the device:

```
  ifconfig eth0:0 192.168.5.12 netmask 255.255.255.0 up
```

You will also need to add this to a system startup script, or add equivalent details to config file. The location of the file depends on your OS & distribution - for example `/etc/rc.d/rc.local` - Read the documentation for your operating system (or tell us the response to `uname -a`).

For Ubuntu see [this article](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/ubuntu-linux-creating-ethernet-alias-for-eth0-network-device.html)

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick 1) Since I'm pinging successfully the first url, it is not possible the issue is with the client-side, right ?

Comment: 2) I've executed ifconfig -a and I don't see any interface with ip XXX.XXX.95.175. I 've root access to unix. Can I fix it by myself and adding the missing interface, or should I call support ?

Comment: Why do you need two IP-addresses? If you paid the provider for two IP-addresses you should call support and find out why your server isn't configured for two IP-addresses. Partly this depends on what sort of arrangement you have with them (VPS, dedicated, ...) - this determines which of you is responsible for configuring the operating system.

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick The ip is supposed to work I need to configure my network configuration. Could you tell me if the snippet I added to the question is ok ?

Comment: @Patrick, I don't have a Ubuntu server to hand at my current location, check the link in my answer above - If in doubt, try using one of the GUI tools mentioned in that article.

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick ok thanks. I'm not very experienced but I'm sure SSL certificates are associated to sockets ip:port

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu uses the '/etc/network/interfaces' file to set permanent ip addresses. So if you would like multiple it would look something like the following:

```
# The primary network interface
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address 10.10.150.13
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    network 10.10.150.0
    broadcast 10.10.150.255
    gateway 10.10.150.254

auto eth0:1
iface eth0:1 inet static
    address 10.10.150.14
    netmask 255.255.255.0
```

Afterwards run 'ifup eth0:1' to enable it.

Comment: So, I even don't need the last line gateway XXX.XXX.150.13 in the second interface ? I want to setup a SSL certificate using the second ip, I will use your configuration if you confirm it is fine.

Comment: Nope, just like the above is sufficient.